# Stripe invoice objects: invoice event object with current_period_end use cases

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am developing a product which is subscription based, billed monthly.
This generates and updates a product key which contains an expiration date.

Currently I am responding to '**customer.subscription.created**' and '**invoice.payment_succeeded**'
With both events, I am using 'current_period_end' *- (unix time in seconds)* to update my product key expiration date.

On a trial created, I expect the 'current_period_end' to be trial period end time.
On payment_succeeded, I expect the 'current_period_end' to the end of the month (*This looks to be correct in tests*)

**My questions are**:

- Is it better to use some other data within the invoice object to get the trail end vs the payment_succeeded event context
- Am I perhaps looking at this the wrong way entirely? Should I lookup the data via some other stripe libary/function, rather than depend on the invoice object.

Note:
The goal here is to make **absolutely** sure expiration date is set accurately for all customer actions via stripe. Links welcome if there are guides available for best practices/strategies.

References:

- [Event types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types)
- [invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object)

***Note to future readers***:
I recommend [this method](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing#trials) for testing subscriptions as I have found the mock singular event calls contain poor quality data/nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumptions

You mention using `current_period_end` to determine your product expiration date.  I will assume you are referring to the Subscription [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_end) since the [Invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object) does not have a property with that name.

#### Questions

- Even an invoice that is generated due to a trial period will trigger an `invoice.payment_succeeded` event.  The amount will just be `0`.  You can use the `amount` value as well as the [billing_reason](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason) to identify trial period related invoices (trials will have an amount of `0` and a reason of `subscription_create`).
- It is unclear to me what the product expiration date you are tracking does in your integration.  However, the approach you describe will keep track of the end of the current billing cycle.  I am guessing you want to track when a customer will lose access to a product if their next payment does not succeed and in that case this approach will work.  That being said, there are a large number of [subscription-specific webhook events](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks).  The public docs describe something almost identical to what you are trying to achieve [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#active-subscriptions).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. And additional information. It is hard to deduce the exact object type as I am using js, and using aws cloudwatch to debug Web hook events. But I believe you are correct, it seems I am receiving slightly different object types depending on event name, further testing will show this. I have marked your answer correct due to the additional docs link.

Comment: Each event type has a specific Stripe object returned in its `data.object` property.  The text is pretty small but the Event Type doc (https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types) does list each one.  For instance, `customer.subscription.created` the event is about the Subscription so that is the object returned and in `invoice.payment_succeeded` the object is the Invoice that just was paid.  You can check which object is returned for each event so you can know what your code needs to handle.

Comment: Perfect thank you! This explains the inconsistency I was getting - each event type giving me a slightly different object.